# switching applications window is behind open programs

Tags: command-line, appmenu

I know pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a window of open apps pops up. 
If I have an application open the pop up window is behind the open app so I can't see it making it essentially useless.
Is there any way where I can set it up where it shows on-top of all other apps?
Also I don't know if it matters but I have a dual screen set up which might be causing this.

Comment: @Tim ubuntu 14 and I have phpStrom on my left monitor and either browser or photoshop on my right monitor, When I click the ALt+TAB I can't see the app window

Comment: What window the pop up or the actual applications im using? And I've that's a setting where can I change it? @Tim

Comment: Right click on the top bar. You might see something like this: https://imgur.com/RbEAJDN. Is that ticked?

Comment: no its not checked @Tim

Comment: @Tim the super+tab goes through the left menu

Comment: Does right super do the same? And what about right alt?